# How do I convert the result?

Tags: pattern-matching, equality, agda

I have this Agda program:

```
data ℕ⁺ : ℕ → Set where
  one : ℕ⁺ (suc zero)
  suc⁺ : {n : ℕ} → ℕ⁺ (suc n)

lemma : ∀ (m n : ℕ) → m ≡ suc n → ℕ⁺ m
lemma m zero p = one
lemma m (suc n) p  = suc⁺ {suc n}
```

The problem is in the second-last line: it complains `one` is not `ℕ⁺ m`, however I have `p` there to prove that they actually are.

How can I do this? I know how do it if what I wanted to prove were in fact an equality (well, just pass `p` in this case), but I don't know how to use `p` to convert a generic `ℕ⁺ m` to `ℕ⁺ (suc zero)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equality type `_≡_` has no special meaning in Agda. To Agda `one` looks like a value of type `ℕ⁺ (suc zero)`, and it needs `ℕ⁺ m`. `transport` should help.

```
transport : forall {A : Set} {B : A → Set} {x y : A} → x ≡ y → B x → B y
transport refl bx = bx

comm : forall {A : Set} {x y : A} → x ≡ y → y ≡ x
comm {x = x} p = transport {B = _≡ x} p refl

lemma : ∀ (m n : ℕ) → m ≡ suc n → ℕ⁺ m
lemma _ _ p  = transport {B = \k → ℕ⁺ k} (comm p) suc⁺
```

(Here I removed `one`, since it is not needed.)

Comment: Thank you! I had guessed that signature actually but I didn't realize its definition was so simple.

Comment: (In the standard library, `transport` is called `subst` and `comm` is called `sym`. Both are defined in `Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality`.)

Answer (score 1):

If you pattern match on `p`, it will refine `m` into `.(suc n)`:

```
lemma : ∀ (m n : ℕ) → m ≡ suc n → ℕ⁺ m
lemma .(suc n) zero    refl = one
lemma .(suc n) (suc n) refl = suc⁺
```

(disclaimer: this is from a non-HoTT/CTT perspective; this probably wouldn't work without [axiom K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39256457/477476).)